# How can i store this table data in session using jsp when click on submit button?

Tags: jsp, session

This is my jsp page, how can I store all values in session for later use.

```
out.println("<table>");
out.println("<tr><td>Movie Name :</td><td ><input type='text' name='movieName' id='movieName' </td></tr>");
out.println("<tr><td >Movie Category:</td><td ><input type='text' name='category' id='category'></td></tr>");
out.println("<tr><td >CD Cost:</td><td ><input type='text' name='cost' id='cost'></td></tr>");
out.println("<tr><td>Release Date:</td><td ><input type='text' name='release' id='release'></td></tr>");
out.println("<tr><td><input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='ValidateAddMovieDetails()'</td></tr>");
out.println("</table>");`'
```

Could anybody guide me how to do this?

Comment: u want to store on input values or all the html data?

Comment: How can i strore javascript variables in session to retrieve in another jsp page?  Check this question@AmanS,this is my actual requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1)

```
out.println("<form id='form1' method='post' action='nextServlet'>");
out.println("<table>");
out.println("<tr><td>Movie Name :</td><td ><input type='text' name='movieName' id='movieName' </td></tr>");
out.println("<tr><td >Movie Category:</td><td ><input type='text' name='category' id='category'></td></tr>");
out.println("<tr><td >CD Cost:</td><td ><input type='text' name='cost' id='cost'></td></tr>");
out.println("<tr><td>Release Date:</td><td ><input type='text' name='release' id='release'></td></tr>");
out.println("<tr><td><input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='ValidateAddMovieDetails()'</td></tr>");
out.println("</table>");
out.println("</form>");
```

2) ---------------------Java Script ---------------

```
function ValidateAddMovieDetails(){

 //validate

 document.getElementById('form1').submit();
}
```

3)
----------------- nextServlet -----------

```
 String movieName=request.getParameter("movieName");
 String category=request.getParameter("category");

 session.setAttribute("movieName",movieName);
 session.setAttribute("category",category);
```

=======================OR================
3)

### Movie.java

```
  public class Movie {

private String movieName;
private String category;
private double cost;
private String release;

public Movie(String movieName, String category, double cost, String release) {
    this.movieName = movieName;
    this.category = category;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.release = release;
}

public String getMovieName() {
    return movieName;
}

public void setMovieName(String movieName) {
    this.movieName = movieName;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public double getCost() {
    return cost;
}

public void setCost(double cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}

public String getRelease() {
    return release;
}

public void setRelease(String release) {
    this.release = release;
}    
}
```

----------------- nextServlet -----------

```
 String movieName=request.getParameter("movieName");
 String category=request.getParameter("category");
 String cost=request.getParameter("cost");
 String release=request.getParameter("release");
  double costd= Double.parseDouble(cost);
Movie mov = new Movie(movieName, category, costd, release);
session.setAttribute("movie",mov);
```

To Get

```
Movie movie = (Movie)session.getAttribute("movie");

String movieName = movie.getMovieName();
String category= movie.getMovieName();
double cost = movie.getCost();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" name="myvar" id="hiddenField">
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("hiddenField").value=yourvar;
```

Now on next page you can get this hidden variable and can easily store it into session variable as following

Second_page
**JSP**

```
<%
    String s=request.getParameter("myvar");
    session.setAttribute("sessionname",s);
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before submitting the jsp, call a javascript function where in take all field:value pair and prepare a json string and post it to the server. At server get a modal object, populate it with form values from json string, this can be easily done using some third party JSON library. Now you can put this modal object in session for future use.

And if you don't want to go with json way, then simply post the form to the server and in your servlet get all fields value using request.getParameter(), populate all modal fields and then put that final modal object in session for future object.